# split string into fixed size groups

Tags: python, string, split

Lets say I have a string...

```
mystr = "abcdefghij"
```

I want to split it so that it becomes a list in groups of two like so...

```
mylist = ['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij']
```

I know there is a `list()` method that will separate every character and a `split()` method that will split on a designated character, but I can't figure out how to split it into groups where there is no whitespace or special character to split on.

Am I just missing something within those two methods, or is there a different way to do this?

Comment: Try this: `"abcdefghij"[2:5]` and then build on this example to do whatever it is you want to do (hint: a string in Python is an iterable object).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `grouper` recipe in `itertools`:

https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#recipes

I think that does what you want in a generic way.